# Compare two vectors in clojure no matter the order of the items

Tags: clojure

I want to compare two vectors and find out if the items they have are the same no matter the order the items are in.

So..

right now in clojure:

```
(= [1 2 3] [3 2 1]) ;=> false
```

I want:

```
(other_fun [1 2 3] [3 2 1]) ;=> true

(other_fun [1 2 3 4] [3 2 1]) ;=> false
```

I could not find a containsAll like in java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't care about duplicates, you could create sets from both vectors and compare these:

```
(= (set [1 2 3]) (set [3 2 1])) ;=> true
```

As a function:

```
(defn set= [& vectors] (apply = (map set vectors)))
```

Comment: I know this is very old, but a bit problematic because set will automatically distinct so it will also return true on (= (set [1 2 3]) (set [1 2 3 3]) for example. 

I think the frequencies answer might be a bit better IMO.

Answer (score 32):

If you *do care* about duplicates, you can compare their frequency maps. These are maps with each collection element as a key and number of occurrences as a value. You create them using standard function `frequencies`, like in given examples.

Different order, same number of duplicates:

`(= (frequencies [1 1 2 3 4])(frequencies [4 1 1 2 3]))`

evaluates `true`.

Different order, different number of duplicates:

`(= (frequencies [1 1 2 3 4])(frequencies [4 1 2 3]))`

evaluates `false`.

So, you can write a function:

```
(defn other_fun [& colls]
  (apply = (map frequencies colls)))
```

Comment: Works for maps too!

Comment: Since Clojure [`=`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/=) equality is by value, `=` indeed works for more complex structures like maps. What a useful language design decision: Favoring productivity over performance. You can still compare by pointer using [`identical?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identical_q) if necessary btw.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't care about duplicates, other answers a perfectly applicable and efficient.
But if you do care about duplicates, probably the easiest way to compare two vectors is sorting and comparing:

```
user=> (= (sort [3 5 2 2]) (sort [2 2 5 3]))
true
user=> (= (sort [3 5 2 2]) (sort [2 5 3]))
false
```

Answer (score 5):

Create sets from them:

```
user=> (= (set [1 2 3]) (set [3 2 1]))
true


user=> (defn other_func [col1 col2]
        (= (set col1) (set col2)))
#'user/other_func
user=> (other_func [1 2 3] [3 2 1])
true
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the JVM already, so if you want containsAll, then just use containsAll, right?

Comment: `containsAll` determines whether one collection is a subset of the other collection. It does not determine set equality.

Comment: @Confusion You can use `a.containsAll(b) && b.containsAll(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn other_fun
  "checkes the presence of the elements of vec1 in vec2 and vice versa"
  [vec1 vec2]
  (if (or (some nil?
             (for [a vec1 b [vec2]]  (some #(= % a) b)))
       (some nil?
             (for [a vec2 b [vec1]]  (some #(= % a) b))))
    false
    true))

(other_fun [1 2 3] [3 2 1]) ;=> true

(other_fun [1 2 3 4] [3 2 1]) ;=> false
```

Comment: You can simplify `(if x false true)` as `(not x)`.