# Maps and keywords in clojure

Tags: clojure, count, maps, keyword

So I do my query on my posts for their eid and I get a list:

> (map :eid (get-all-posts))

```
(17592186045421 17592186045438 17592186045440 17592186045540 
 17592186045545 17592186045550 17592186045588 17592186045590 
 17592186045592 17592186045594 17592186045597 17592186045608 
 17592186045616 17592186045721 17592186045866 17592186046045 
 17592186046047 17592186046075 17592186046077 17592186046079 
 17592186046081 17592186046083 17592186046085 17592186046088 
 17592186046149 17592186046158 17592186046170 17592186046174 
 17592186046292 17592186046352 17592186046362 17592186047146 
 17592186047211)
```

Every post can have many :ratings,

> (get-all-ratings 17592186047211)

```
({:rating "positive", 
  :rid 17592186047652, 
  :email "vaso@ph"} 
 {:rating "positive", 
  :rid 17592186047756, 
  :email "sova.kua@gmcom"} 
 {:rating "meh", 
  :rid 17592186047725, 
 :email "badger@ton"})
```

Would like to combine the maps so I can `(count) the number of ratings per post.

> (count (get-all-ratings 17592186047211)

```
 3
```

But trying something like

> (count (map get-all-ratings (map :eid (get-all-posts)))

simply returns the number of posts... it's a big list like

```
(({:rating "plus", :rid 7175 ..}
  {:rating "plus" :rid 7374})
 ({:rating "whatever", :rid 7535})
 ()
 () <some have no ratings
 ({:rating "green", :rid 7152}))
```

How can I tally up the number of times :rating shows up in a list of listed maps like above?

```
>(map :rating (map first (map get-all-ratings (map :eid (get-all-posts)))))
```

is something I've been playing with, and it returns a list, but as you can probably tell, it just returns one :rating field from each post's expanded ratings map.

Edit:
I noticed just now that something like

```
({:rating 5}
 {:rating 3}
 {:rating 7})
```

just becomes

```
 {:rating 7}
```

...disregarding other entries in the list.  How come?

Comment: just to clarify a bit, based on the usage example, get-all-ratings can accept a eid or sequence of eids as parameter right? because in one example, you give it a eid and in the other example, you give it the result of a map function

Comment: it can only accept an eid. made a mistake in my example..  (map get-all-ratings (map :eid (get-all-posts))) is accurate creates the [abbreviated] "big list" above

Comment: achieved what I wanted using (frequencies)  ...see this answer for an illustrative example http://stackoverflow.com/a/8389828